# Adding a Column to a Generic List INstance during feature provisioning

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to create a solution package for a set of features within a SharePoint site. I want to create an instance of a generic list (using ListInstance in the element manifest) and add an additional column to it (since by default they only have a Title column) without having to go through activation code.

Is there a way to do this through CAML? So, far I'm sort of stuck with the idea of having to create a custom content type but that means I would have to have a separate feature that activates at the Site level to deploy the content type first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx) is what you are looking for, snippets:

```
<!--Add a field reference for the custom field.-->
<FieldRef
 ID="{AD22016D-BC8B-4631-A0A3-5E84C6CFA7EC}" 
 Name="FavoriteColor" 
 Required="TRUE" 
 ShowInNewForm="TRUE" 
 ShowInEditForm="TRUE"/>
```

and then:

`<Fields>
      <Field 
        Type="Choice" 
        Name="FavoriteColor" 
        DisplayName="Favorite Color">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>Red</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Green</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Blue</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
      </Field>
    </Fields>`

Making sure it is added to the view`<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="FavoriteColor"/>
</ViewFields>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I was hoping not to go through the process of creating a List Definition. I just wanted to add an instance of the Generic list and add a column through the provisioning process. Creating a list definition is a lot of extra markup just to add one more column.

Comment: Try this link then: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/09/08/sharepoint-how-to-provisioning-a-site-column-with-caml.aspx it creates the column only and then you can achieve what you described. Hope this helps with the solution!